# Existe alguma forma de saber se alguem esta referenciando algum arquivo do meu site em outro?

Tags: html, apache, servidor, log

eu tenho uma foto no meu site logomarca.jpg
se alguma espertinho resovelver usar a minha imagem que demorei horas pra fazer e usar no seu site em uma tag  existe a possibilidade de saber daonde esta vindo a requisicao de origem ao arquivo no meu servidor?

Comment: valendo 50 pontos

Comment: Preocupado com propriedade intelectual ou tráfego *clandestino*?  Se for o primeiro, a pessoa pode baixar sua logomarca e servir de outro servidor, não tem como saber isso. Se for o segundo, é possível verificar o log de acesso.

Comment: nao cara eu usei um pouco de sensacionalismo pra ver se algum fi de deus resolveria responder a minha pergunta

Comment: Pode, via javascript armazenar os alegados ips de quem fez cliques (botão direito ou botão esquerdo do rato) na imagem. Se é mesmo para ver se a sua imagem está a sua usada em algum lado o google é o melhor, é só arrastar a imagem para aí https://www.google.pt/search?q=.&hl=pt-PT&biw=1308&bih=857&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ8__WwvzMAhXBfhoKHe5EAsYQ_AUIBigB

Comment: depois que eu pegar o ip eu dou queixa na delegacia rs eu so quero saber se e possivel identifar esses tipo de atividade mas nao dexa de ser um boa ideia @Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível saber quem fez a requisição através do [cabeçalho **Referer** do HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14). Isso geralmente fica armazenado em log num arquivo `access.log`, mas depende da configuração e de qual servidor você está usando.

Obs: se sua página for HTTP e o servidor externo (que está referenciando seu recurso) for HTTPS, você não receberá os dados do Referer [por questões de segurança](http://smerity.com/articles/2013/where_did_all_the_http_referrers_go.html). Mas será possível identificar atividade estranha, já que as requisições desse recurso a partir do seu site incluirão o seu próprio host como Referer, já requisições externas incluirão outro ou nenhum host.

Comment: possa ser que esses sistemas de ids tem algum que monitore em tempo real vou dar uma pesquisada